# how to find another element on the same row when given a array element in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe dataset it contains 1000 rows,
a part of the dataset looks like this:

```
{
"keywords": 
[
"joyride",
"motorway",
"140km/h",
"8-yr-old",
"Germany",
"child",
"police",
"Dortmund",
"lay-by",
"Wednesday",
"parents",
"warning",
"eight-year-old",
"mother",
"automatic",
"Golf",
"Soest",
"Volkswagen",
"high",
"The alarm",
"A44",
"go-karts",
"Volkswagen Golf",
"Berlin",
"IANS",
"triangle",
"bumper cars"
],

"hashtags": 
[
"#ControlledaccessHighway",
"#Germany",
"#RestArea",
"#Dortmund",
"#Berlin",
"#IANS",
"#IndoAsianNewsService",
"#A44Road",
"#Triangle",
"#KartRacing",
"#BumperCars",
"#VolkswagenGolf",
"#SoestGermany",
"#TheAlarm"
],

"label": "200"}
,

{"keywords": 
[
"Eight-year-old",
"140kph",
"parent",
"mother",
"police",
"lay-by",
"child",
"property",
"family",
"cars",
"autobahn",
"warning",
"night",
"late",
"87mph",
"eight-year-old",
"motorway",
"joyride",
"German",
"minutes",
"dash",
"Soest",
"journalism",
"private property",
"Facebook",
"A44",
"go-karts",
"Dortmund",
"VW Golf",
"free-thinking",
"Germany",
"triangle",
"bumper cars"
],

"hashtags": 
[
"#A44Road",
"#Autobahn",
"#RestArea",
"#Germany",
"#ControlledaccessHighway",
"#VolkswagenGolf",
"#SoestGermany",
"#Dortmund",
"#Triangle",
"#Facebook",
"#PrivateProperty",
"#BumperCars",
"#KartRacing",
"#Freethought",
"#Journalism"
], 

"label": "200"
}
}
```

Given an array variable so-called "temp" which is the same as one of the elements in "hashtags" column, I tried several methods to locate what is the "label" element of it such as:

```
label = df.loc[df['hashtags'] == temp, "label" ].iloc[0]
print(label)
```

It always return the error:

```
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 1000 vs 21
```

But when I use "label"(which is a number) to locate other columns it doesn't return the error. How can I fix this problem if I want to keep using "hashtag" as a input?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: `item.values[0]`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please put at least the effort into your question you expect from others when answering. Your example data is not valid python, attempt to assign it to a variable failed and trying to fix it would mean guessing which is futile. And both `labels` in your example data are identical - so the clue of your task is also not really clear... all in all: please clarify for people which are completely new to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC and your dataframe looks like

```
df 
                                        keywords  ... label
0  [joyride, motorway, 140km/h, 8-yr-old, Germany...  ...   200
1  [Eight-year-old, 140kph, parent, mother, polic...  ...   200
```

Example:

```
temp = '#Berlin'
```

You can receive the indices of where temp is to find with

```
df.hashtags.apply(lambda v: temp in v)

# 0     True
# 1    False
# Name: hashtags, dtype: bool
```

the corresponding labels are therefore

```
df.label.loc[df.hashtags.apply(lambda v: temp in v)]

# 0    200
# Name: label, dtype: object
```

or for several temp-values:

```
for temp in ['#Berlin', '#BumperCars', '#Journalism']:
    print(temp, '\n', df.label.loc[df.hashtags.apply(lambda v: temp in v)], '\n')

#Berlin 
# 0    200
# Name: label, dtype: object 

#BumperCars 
# 0    200
# 1    200
# Name: label, dtype: object 

#Journalism 
# 1    200
# Name: label, dtype: object
```